# how to apply a function to multiple elements with the same name in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, tags

I am using [tagify.js](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) plugin where you can add tags into an input. I have 2 modals, each contains an input where you can add usernames as tags.

```
<input class="form-control" name="tags"></input>
```

As the attribute `name` can be added to multiple inputs not necessary must be unique as `id` attribute, I kept the `name="tags"` in both modal.

The problem is when I apply the plugin and add tags to the inputs it's applied only to the input of first modal and not the second.

As you see in the screenshot, in first modal I can select tags inside the input but in the second modal it's empty.
[image]

The function I created doesn't generate any error. I tried `console.log` each variable I have but I couldn't figure out where the issue is.

Any suggestions please what am I doing wrong ? Thank you very much.

Here is my running [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/a0kAjGVHZluwWgpj?open=lib%2Fscript.js). I added comments for better understanding.

http://plnkr.co/edit/a0kAjGVHZluwWgpj?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: `As the attribute name can be added to multiple inputs not necessary must be unique as id attribute, I kept the name="tags" in both modal.` this is "usually" accomplished by using the "class" property to group like things together.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `querySelector` select only the first,

if you want select all, you have to use `querySelectorAll`

```
var inputElm = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=tags]');
```

in this case inputElm is an array with all input founded and you have to modify your code to use the different elements. ($.each or other loop). And you have to create an instance of tagify for each input. I suggest you to use an array of tagify.

Something like that:

```
var tagify = [];
inputElm.each(function(){
    var tag = new Tagify($(this),...
      :
    tagify.push(tag);
}
```